# Add a (foot)note in my bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, footnotes, notes

I would like to add a footnote, or any other kind of note, to my bibliography. I have references from 2 different `.bibtex` files, and I need to make a distinction between the two. Currently, I put a `*` in the Author's name to mark the difference. Now, I would like to add a footnote, or any other note, to mark that the `*` indicates the difference.

Example:

```
\bibliography{file1, file2}
\footnote{*: Different reference}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

When I add this, it creates an entirely new page, before or after my bibliography. This is not what I want. Could anybody help me with this?

I am using documentclass article.

Answer (score 3):

With the KOMA-Script class `scrartcl` you have a command `\setbibpreamble{...}` to set a text before your bibliography starts.

Please see the following MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}        % loading package filecontents
% writing file \jobname.bib, for example mb-bibtex.bib.
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname1.bib}
@Book{companion,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year       = {1994}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname2.bib}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ragged2e}                % pretty bib preamble
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}         % bibliography style
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}    % better urls in bibliography

\begin{document}
Test of bibliography: 
The \LaTeX{} companion~\cite{companion}, the funny book of 
Adams~\cite{adams}. 
\nocite{*}  % print all bib entrys in bibliography 

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}  % needs package natbib
\setbibpreamble{\justifying\noindent The asterix marks ... \par\bigskip\RaggedRight} 
\bibliography{\jobname1,\jobname2}    % uses \jobname1.bib, according to \jobname.tex
\end{document}
```

resulting in:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by adding a margin note.

Insert:

```
\usepackage{marginnote}
```

in the preamble and then insert the margin note before/after the bibliography. Like so:

```
\bibliography{file1, file2}
\marginpar{* = Different reference}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```